# Ver as chamadas recursivas no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, recursão

Existe alguma ferramenta do eclipse que mostre as chamadas recursivas como nessa imagem? Onde eu possa ver os detalhes de preferência de forma gráfica?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## javashot

Existe algo parecido. Há um projeto chamado [*javashot*](https://github.com/arebya/javashot) que lança mão de instrumentalização das classes Java para capturar informações de chamadas de métodos.

O projeto não tem manutenção frequente, mas dado que a plataforma Java em geral mantém retro-compatibilidade, ele deve funcionar com as versões mais novas da plataforma.

Na [documentação](https://code.google.com/p/javashot/), há um exemplo que gera um gráfico da inicialização do servidor Jetty:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A geração do gráfico faz uso de algumas ferramentas de sistemas *unix-like*, então pode ser um pouco complicado obter os mesmos resultados em sistemas Windows.

## Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform (TPTP)

Para informações mais detalhadas, embora sem o gráfico como descrito na pergunta, o plugin Eclipse TPTP pode ser usado.

Ele é capaz de gerar informações detalhadas sobre [execução de métodos para *profiling*](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html#3_4) e [alguns diagramas de execução](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html#3_4), por exemplo:

[image: Diagrama de sequência]

[image: Fluxo de chamadas]